# Animate a box with a lid (scenekit)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit

I have a .dae 3d box from Sketchup with a lid, imported into Xcode. To open the lid (either slide or lift) - must the lid be constructed as a separate file and as a separate node? Or can individual elements in the same box be moved around? Please advice a strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to have it as a separate node with its own geometry that you can then manipulate individually.

Comment: Some days ago I got this answer from StackExchange by mail "One file, two nodes is the simplest." But I never saw this answer online... Anyways - that solved my problem. I used the same Sketchup file, and extracted the lid into its own node by using 'let lid = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("lid", recursively: true)!'   (I changed the name from instance_4 to lid in the .dae viewer in Xcode). I was then able to move the lid separately from the box itself by using a SCNAction on the lid. Thx.

Comment: you would typically have separate files for an environment scene, a character and a collectible item. That way it's easier to work with an artist and your resources are better organized. If your object has multiple parts, the easiest thing to do is to have one file and several nodes, yes. That way you can instantiate the object several times, don't have to manage separate scenes in your code, etc.